# Strange error on 29.10.2011 till 31.10.2011 counting the nights wrong

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i use two datepickers to get the arrival and the departure date, counting the days for the number of nights, all is working nice, except one thing: if i take my startdate on 29.10.2011 and my enddate on the 31.10.2011 jquery counts 3 nights but there only 2 nights. Only in october, other month still working fine, hope someone could help me to figure out where my mistake is:

```
var oneDay = 1000*60*60*24; 
var difference = Math.ceil((arrivalDate.getTime() - departureDate.getTime()) / oneDay);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that daylight saving time ends on 30th October in Europe (where, going by the German error message, you are).  As a result, where there would normally be 24+24+24=72 hours between the dates, in this case, there are 24+24+24+1=73 hours between the dates.  Your code therefore works out that there are 2.041666 days between the dates.  Your `Math.ceil` then rounds this up to 3.

The simplest solution to this in this case is probably just to replace `Math.ceil` with `Math.round`.  When DST ends, your 2.04166 days will be rounded to 2 days.  When DST starts, the 1.95834 days you'll work out then will also be rounded to 2 days.

Comment: +1, nice one! that means that op should also take March under consideration. If instead of using `Ceil` she would use `Floor` October would be fixed, but it would also messed up March

Comment: Jandrejc, good point.  I've added a solution which should work at both ends of the year.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Javascript was configured to adjust for daylight saving time.

Comment: Lazarus, if you think about it, it has to be able to do this in order to provide accurate answers to getTime() - the number of milliseconds since 1st January 1970.  More prosaically, a DST problem is the only real way to get the effect that the questioner describes.

Comment: I hate that, first comment. I was right. And it's ignored. :(

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
var difference = Math.ceil((arrivalDate.getTime() - departureDate.getTime()) / oneDay);
```

to:

```
var different = Math.Floor(arrivalDate.getTime() / oneDay) - Math.Floor(departureDate.getTime() / oneDay)
```

Comment: You're right that your answer solves the problem - but it doesn't explain what the problem is.  That might be why your answer got overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

March should not get messed up, because it just one hour less, so it still gets round up to 24 hours, if i'm correct?

Greetings Ralf

Answer (score 0):

The following correctly reports 2 'nights' or in fact 2 days.

```
var startDate = new Date(2011,10,29);
var endDate = new Date(2011,10,31);
var oneDay = 1000*86400;
var difference = Math.ceil((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/oneDay);
alert(difference);
```

I suspect the problem is with the time aspect of the Date object. You could 'clean' the inputs by removing the time element thus.

```
function JustDate(inputDate) {
    return new Date(inputDate.getFullYear(), inputDate.getMonth(), inputDate.getDate());
}

var departureDate = JustDate(departure.datepicker("getDate"));
var arrivalDate = JustDate(arrival.datepicker("getDate"));
```